# Timestamp For Discord Bot Status

Tags: node.js, discord.js, bots

I am using Discord.js Node V12 I am currently trying to find out how to say time elapsed in the status to show how long the bot has been playing game or any activity. But i cannot find anyone who has asked or answered any of these questions.

```py
@client.event
async def on_connect():
  await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.dnd,activity = discord.Game(name = "VALORANT"))
```

Comment: That looks like python, not javascript.

Comment: you used the discord.py tag, and you have discord.py code in the question and you're saying you're using discord.js node v12?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to break this answer into a few significant points:

• The sample code provided is from discord.py ( a discontinued python based library to interact with the API ) which is totally out of context of the whole question itself since you're asking it for discord.js

• There is no actual way to find the time elapsed since a particular activity as of now but you may resort to this:

```js
var uptime = client.uptime; // returns uptime in milliseconds
var hours = uptime / 1000 / 60 / 60 // converts it to hours 
/* 
Then you may apply the following approach to change your status every hour passes 
*/
setInterval(() => {
    client.user.setActivity(`Valorant since ${hours} hour(s)`);
  }, 3600000); // this would show up as Playing Valorant since 1 hour(s) and subsequently would change every hour if your bot isn't being restarted continuously.
```

Comment: OP wrote his question in python, not Javascript. `setInterval` is also highly inefficient for what OP is trying to achieve. Perhaps try calculating what millisecond value (or what time it will be in 1 hour) then check periodically whether it is that time.

Comment: I agree with you Joe that they wrote their code in python however it clearly has a discord.js tag with them metioning that they're using nodejs V12 with discord.js, plus I agree with `setInterval()` not being a very efficient method for this, I suggest `node-cron` for scheduled status changes :)

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the [discord.js documentation to examine setting activities](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setActivity) and found no such information about timestamps. However, there was a section in the [`ActivityType`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ActivityType) that led me to the [discord developers documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#activity-object-activity-structure) and it indicates:

> Bots are only able to send `name`, `type`, and optionally `url`.

So it doesn't seem as though you will be able to set the start or end timestamps for an activity as a bot.